# packages not loaded when migrating to webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm migrating a rails application from `sprockets` to `webpacker`. I having problem loading packages in my layout. I have to manually include packages that are included in my pack. Is this to be expected or can it be fixed?

***error***

```js
Uncaught Error: Include d3.js (v3.0.3 or greater) and topojson on this page before creating a new map
    at new l (datamaps.usa.min.js:1)
    at (index):226
(index):298 Uncaught ReferenceError: shortcut is not defined
    at (index):298
```

***app/javascript/packs/client_application.js***

```js
require("jquery")
require("shortcut.js/shortcut")
require("topojson")
require("d3/d3.min")
require("js/d3_tip")
```

***client.haml(not working)***

```rb
= javascript_pack_tag "client_application"
```

***client.haml(works)***

```rb
= javascript_pack_tag "client_application"
= javascript_include_tag "shortcut.js/shortcut"
= javascript_include_tag "d3/d3.min"
= javascript_include_tag "topjson"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the following workflow works for me (using `d3` as an example):

**1. Add the package via `yarn`**

```
yarn add d3
```

**2. config/webpack/environment.js**

Create an alias for the package that has just been added:

```
const aliasConfig = {
  'd3': 'd3/dist/d3.js'
};

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', aliasConfig);
```

The alias has to point to the main JS file of the package, relative to the `node_modules` folder.

**3. app/javascript/packs/application.js**

Add the import:

```
import "d3"
```

**Bonus**

As an alternative, you can skip #2 and add an extra line to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` assigning the imported library to the global window object:

```
window.d3 = d3
```